Copy Sheet from Workbook to Another Workbook without deleting/changing existing values, formulas, formatting, etc. to target Excel Workbook
I am basically taking a raw data set, and importing it into another workbook that is heavily used by me with formulas/values/formatting/column grouping already existing in the target workbook.I want to copy the raw data into the existing sheet in another workbook without it changing anything else in the target spreadsheet.
I have the basic Pandas copy, and understand that this will copy over the spreadsheet, and delete all the other values. 
I think my logic may be wrong, and I need to grab the data set I want copied and turn it into a Pandas Data Frame, and copy that to the target column/row and maybe that won't delete/change the existing values in the cells?
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/mikey/Desktop/Automating Financial Reporting/QBO Spreadsheets/Statement of Cash Flows/StatementofCashFlows-ABC.xlsx', sheet_name="Month")

data.to_excel('/Users/mikey/Desktop/Automating Financial Reporting/QBO Spreadsheets/Statement of Cash Flows/StatementofCashFlows-ABCReporting.xlsx',sheet_name="ABC Cash Flows",startcol=17,startrow=9,index=False,header=None)


What is the question exactly? Are you trying to copy your dataset to a workbook without affecting the existing formulas and formatting in the workbook?

Correct.  I want to copy the raw data into the an existing sheet in another workbook.

The default engine used here is Xlsxwriter which will always create a new Excel file, overwriting the existing if it indeed does already exist.
If you want to leave existing sheets/data as is then use Openpyxl as the engine in append mode ('a').
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_excel('/Users/mikey/Desktop/Automating Financial Reporting/QBO Spreadsheets/Statement of Cash Flows/StatementofCashFlows-ABC.xlsx', sheet_name="Month")

output_excel_file = '/Users/mikey/Desktop/Automating Financial Reporting/QBO Spreadsheets/Statement of Cash Flows/StatementofCashFlows-ABCReporting.xlsx'


with pd.ExcelWriter(output_excel_file,
                    mode='a',
                    if_sheet_exists='overlay', 
                    engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer,
                  sheet_name="ABC Cash Flows",
                  startcol=17,
                  startrow=9,
                  index=False,
                  header=False
    )

The if_sheet_exists param, which is required in append mode, determines what happens if the Sheet you specify to write to, 'ABC Cash Flows', already exists. You can check all the options and what they do here
The specific setting used here;
overlay: Write contents to the existing sheet without first removing, but possibly over top of, the existing contents. would be the option you want. The dataframe will be written to the existing Sheet and only overwrite data that falls in the same range as the dataframe with the start row and column settings you have specified.

Thanks man, this worked.  I was looking at the ExcelWriter documentation and pretty much confused myself.  New to Python so this has helped tremendously.
